# Malloc pointer being freed was not allocated error when calling initWithBitmapData

Tags: ios, objective-c, ciimage

When I create a CIImage by calling this routine I get the malloc error in the title.  When I call initWithBitmapData directly (not within the createCIUimageFromData routine) then it works fine.

I have seen references to possible bugs in iOS that might be related, but I can't tell for sure and I certainly suspect my code more than Apple's!

My guess is somehow my additional redirection is screwing things up, but it's cleaner to have the separate routine than to embed the code wherever I need it.

Thank you.

Fails:

```
- (CIImage *) createCIimageFromData : (unsigned char *)pData   width : (int32_t)width height : (int32_t)height
{

    /*
     Once we have the raw data, we convert it into a CIImage.
     The following code does the required work.
     */
    NSLog(@"entering createciimage\n");
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    NSData *_pixelsData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:pData length:(sizeof(unsigned char)*width*height) freeWhenDone:YES ];
    CIImage *_dataCIImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapData:_pixelsData bytesPerRow:(width*sizeof(unsigned char)) size:CGSizeMake(width,height) format:kCIFormatR8 colorSpace:colorSpaceRef];

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

    /*
     newImage is the final image
     Do remember to release the allocated parts.
     */
    NSLog(@"done ciimage\n");
    return _dataCIImage;
}
```

Works:

```
void prepData(unsigned char *pData,  // source-destination
                           int strideSrc, // stride
                           int width,
                           int height,
                           double amount,
                           int deltaLimit,
                           id owner)
{

   //[owner createCIimageFromData:pData width:width height:height];  // <-- commented out
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    NSData *_pixelsData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:pData length:(sizeof(unsigned char)*width*height) freeWhenDone:YES ];
    CIImage *_dataCIImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapData:_pixelsData bytesPerRow:(width*sizeof(unsigned char)) size:CGSizeMake(width,height) format:kCIFormatR8 colorSpace:colorSpaceRef];

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

// . . .
}
```

Comment: Try `freeWhenDone:NO`, and free the data after you're done with the `CIImage`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have done the job!  If you add it as an answer I can indicate that this was the answer.

Comment: @ user938797 Let's wait and see if somebody can tell you ***why*** this is the answer. I was just guessing :) It would be useful to know what's going on behind the scenes that causes the problem. So we all know what to avoid in the future.

Comment: OK, I'm ready to give you credit when the time is right!

Comment: I'm going to call this solved and closed.  If you make yours the answer I'll give you credit.  user3386109

Comment: Not related to your problem, but: `sizeof(char)` is, by definition, 1. `sizeof` measures in units of `char`s, not (technically) bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently the problem is caused when the `NSData` object attempts to free the data. To avoid the problem, use `freeWhenDone:NO` and then free the data after you're done with the `CIImage`.

Comment: The problem with the `NoCopy` methods (regardless of `freeWhenDone`) is that you have to make sure that the data buffer pointed to by `pData` and referenced by the `NSData` object lives as long as that `NSData` object, which is likely retained by the `CIImage`. So, it has to live as long as that `CIImage`, too. And, since both are reference counted, there's no telling how long they will live. They can live past when you release your last strong reference to them, because any code which they ever passed through could retain them for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks Ken Thomases, that helps as well.